# how can I copy to clipboard text from a JS vairable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

in JS, I have a variable

```
var text = "this is a test";
```

and when I click a button in my HTML, it calls a JS funciton

```
function nameoffunction(){
}
```

I want to copy to the clipboard "this is a test" when the function is called.

How can I do that ?

Comment: https://clipboardjs.com/

Comment: clipboardjs.com was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
<script>
  function CopyToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");

  // Place in top-left corner of screen regardless of scroll position.
  textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
  textArea.style.top = 0;
  textArea.style.left = 0;

  // Ensure it has a small width and height. Setting to 1px / 1em
  // doesn't work as this gives a negative w/h on some browsers.
  textArea.style.width = '2em';
  textArea.style.height = '2em';

  // We don't need padding, reducing the size if it does flash render.
  textArea.style.padding = 0;

  // Clean up any borders.
  textArea.style.border = 'none';
  textArea.style.outline = 'none';
  textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none';

  // Avoid flash of white box if rendered for any reason.
  textArea.style.background = 'transparent';


  textArea.value = text;

  document.body.appendChild(textArea);

  textArea.select();

  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}


var copyBtn = document.querySelector('#CopyBtn');

copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var text = "this is a test";
  CopyToClipboard(text);
});

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<p>
<button id="CopyBtn">Copy to clipboard</button>
</p>
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)